# Proper way with combining vue and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Lets say I have user profile and this is user image:

```
<div class="user-image">
  <img src="{{ $user->image }}">
</div>
```

And if I am visiting profile as owner:

```
<div class="user-image">
  <img src="{{ $user->image }}">
  <div class="change">
    <input type="file" name="userImage">
  </div>
</div>
```

In laravel we can do it with:

```
<div class="user-image">
  <img src="{{ $user->image }}">
  @if(auth()->user() && auth()->user()->id === $user->id)
  <div class="change">
    <input type="file" name="userImage">
  </div>
  @endif
</div>
```

Now I achieve this in Vue like this:

Template 1 as `<user-image>`:

```
<div class="user-image">
  <img src="{{ $user->image }}">
  <slot name="changeImage"></slot>
</div>
```

Template 2 as `<change-image>`:

```
<div class="change">
  <input type="file" name="userImage">
</div>
```

Now I use this in `profile.blade.php`:

```
<user-image>
  @if(auth()->user() && auth()->user()->id === $user->id)
  <change-image></change-image>
  @endif
</user-image>
```

This works fine, but how can I do this if I use whole front in vue where I do everything in App.vue and then render it to base page?

I guess I can use v-if with something like `window.isOwner = true;`

And then I add it to vuex store as:

```
state: {
  isOwner: window.isOwner;
}
```

And use `this.$store.state.isOwner with v-if or v-show`, but as well we can access state through browser console:

`document.getelementbyid('app').__vue__.$store.state.isOwner` and change it to true if it is false, and because of it would alter v-if...

So what is the proper way of hiding some element from non owner users within vue components?

Thanks

Comment: i recommend to use the backend code for that critic operations

Comment: So I can't do all front in vue? :D